# Line integral of a conservative vector field which has a potential - Issues factoring derivatives

Tags: calculus, derivatives, physics, vector-fields

> Let $F = −\nabla \phi$ be a conservative force field. Suppose a particle of mass $m$ moves in this field. If $A$ and $B$ are any two points in space, prove that 
>   $$
> \phi(A) + \frac{m}{2} v_A^2 = \phi(B) + \frac{m}{2} v_B^2 ,
> $$
>   where $v_A = \|dr(A)/dt \|$ and $vB = \| dr(B)/dt \|$ are the magnitudes of the velocities of the particle at $A$ and $B$, respectively.

Using the fact that $F = − \nabla \phi$ is a conservative field we have 
$$
\int F \cdot dr = \int (-\nabla \phi) \cdot dr = \phi(A) - \phi(B)
$$
We also have that $F = m \frac{d^2 r}{dt^2}$ and hence if $r = (r_1(t),r_2(t),r_3(t))$ we have
R
   d2r dr  F•dr=m • dt=(r1′′r1′ +r2′′r2′ +r3′′r3′)dt dt2 dt

I believe I can factor out $d/dt$ but I'm unsure where $1/2$ comes from...as I want $\frac{m}{2} v^2|AB$.
How do I finish this?

Comment: MathJaX would really help. I started, could you please finish it?

Comment: That looks soo much better!! I want to do this...I have an exam tomorrow in Vector Calculus, how do I use MathJax?

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track

$$
-\nabla \phi = m\frac{{\rm d}^2 {\bf r}}{{\rm d}t^2} = m\frac{{\rm d}{\bf v}}{{\rm d}t} \tag{1}
$$

Multiply both sides by ${\bf v}$:

$$
-\nabla \phi \cdot {\bf v} = m  {\bf v} \cdot\frac{{\rm d}{\bf v}}{{\rm d}t} = \frac{1}{2}m \frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}t}({\bf v}\cdot {\bf v}) = \frac{1}{2}m\frac{{\rm d}v^2}{{\rm d}t} \tag{2}
$$

Now integrate on both sides

$$
-\int \nabla \phi \cdot \frac{{\rm d}{\bf r}}{{\rm d}t}{\rm d}t = -\int \nabla \phi \cdot {\rm d}{\bf r} = -\int{\rm d}\phi =  \frac{1}{2}m\int \frac{{\rm d}v^2}{{\rm d}t} \tag{3}
$$

And from here you conclude that

$$
H = \phi + \frac{1}{2}mv^2 
$$

is a constant

Comment: Thank you, this is nicely put together... although I'm still unsure how this 1/2 enters on the second line.

Comment: @ConnorBuckley $$ \frac{{\rm d}v^2}{{\rm d}t} =  \frac{{\rm d}({\bf v}\cdot {\bf v})}{{\rm d}t} = {\bf v}\cdot \frac{{\rm d}{\bf v}}{{\rm d}t} +  \frac{{\rm d}{\bf v}}{{\rm d}t} \cdot  {\bf v} =   {\bf v}\cdot \frac{{\rm d}{\bf v}}{{\rm d}t}  +  {\bf v}\cdot \frac{{\rm d}{\bf v}}{{\rm d}t}  = \color{red}{2}{\bf v}\cdot \frac{{\rm d}{\bf v}}{{\rm d}t} 
$$

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I got stuck on this! I've done a LOT of maths today, thank you!!